# O que é o protocolo MQTT?

Tags: terminologia, mqtt

Esses dias ouvi falar de um protocolo de comunicação chamado MQTT.

Para mim soou como novidade e gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas:

- O que é o MQTT?
- Ele usa TCP?
- Ele tem alguma diferença em relação ao HTTP?

Comment: Está falando disso https://mqtt.org/ ? Se for é IoT (internet das coisas) ... Creio que não tenha nada haver com HTTP. Resumindo é um *"protocolo próprio"* que roda em cima de TCP, mas não sou entendido do assunto, talvez não seja uma pergunta on-topic.

Comment: Esse mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### MQ Telemetry Transport (MQTT)

O MQT atualmente é o protocolo padrão para internet das coisas. Isto se torna claro já que ele é projetado para transporte e assinatura de mensagens extremamente leves e com pouco uso de banda da rede. Ele transporta suas mensagens sobre o TCP e usa SSL/TLS para segurança.

### Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)

O HTTP é utilizado como base de formatação da World Wide Web. É o protocolo responsável pela ação que um servidor deve realizar ao enviar informações pela rede. Só dei uma breve introdução ao HTTP, pois ele não é o ponto principal da pergunta.

### Diferenças MQTT e HTTP

---

O MQTT é centrado em dados, com isto é mais simples e possui mais leveza, pois *suas mensagens são em formato binário* e seu cabeçalho tem no máximo dois bits. Ele segue o modelo de publicação/assinatura, que faz com que mensagem chegue no servidor e não o "tranque" ficando esperando a resposta, podendo fazer vários envios.

De acordo com medições em redes 3G, o throughput do MQTT é 93 vezes mais rápido do que o HTTP.

MQTT tem especificações bastante curtas. Praticamente os únicos tipos usados são o CONNECT, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE e DISCONNECT.

---

Já o HTTP é centrado em documentos, então suas mensagens seguem o padrão ASCII e o cabeçalho tem 8bytes. Segue o modelo de solicitação/resposta, por este motivo tem que ficar esperando a resposta do servidor quando faz uma requisição podendo travar o sistema.

Ele não oferece padrões de segurança como SSL/TLS, mas ele já foi criado para ser um padrão de segurança.

**Curiosidade:** O MQTT funciona na porta 1883 enquanto o HTTP na 80 ou 8080.

### Conclusão

Tanto o HTTP como o MQTT é valido para se usar, mas o MQTT já foi criado para transmissões mais simples como internet da coisas, por este motivo é recomendado o uso para este fim.

Answer (score 4):

- O MQTT- **Message Queue Telemetry Transport** é um Protocolo de
  Comunicação baseado na pilha TCP/IP, sendo extremamente útil para
  desenvolvimento de projetos de comunicação entre Máquina-Máquina
  (M2M), seu conceito de transmissão é do tipo
  **Publicação/Assinatura**.
- Desenvolvido por Andy Stanford-Clark da IBM e Arlen Nipper em 1999,
  sua aplicação de origem consistia em monitorar sensores em oleodutos
  de petróleo através de satélites, o MQTT foi liberado ao público de
  forma gratuita no ano de 2010. Em 29 de outubro de 2014 o protocolo
  se tornou padrão **OASIS- Organization for the Advancement of
  Structured Information Standards**. Atualmente o protocolo está em
  sua versão 5.0 (3 de abril de 2019), com melhorias no que tange o
  relatório de erros, as assinaturas compartilhadas, as propriedades da
  mensagem, expiração de mensagens, expiração da sessão, alias do
  tópico, função atraso na entrega e descoberta de funções permitidas.
- O MQTT apresenta inúmeras qualidades e vantagens com relação a outros
  protocolos como o HTTP, mostrando-se ideal para comunicação entre
  dispositivos remotos em razão de sua qualidade de serviço, maior
  nível de segurança, facilidade de implementação, baixa alocação de
  banda, bibliotecas compatíveis com diversas linguagens de
  programação, seu conceito de distribuição, níveis de serviço de
  acordo com relevância da mensagem, garantias de entrega, variações de
  envio de dados, sendo que um dado pode ser enviado para nenhum, um,
  ou vários clientes, entre outras qualidades que o tornam ideal para
  **projetos IoT**.
- A publicação e recebimento de dados são feitos através de um servidor
  nomeado de Broker. Um cliente no papel de Pulicador ou Publisher, que
  é a pessoa que transmite a mensagem, escreve um tópico de destino da
  mensagem e o seu Payload (conteúdo da mensagem), essa mensagem então
  é transmitida ao Broker que será responsável por gerir e encaminhá-la
  ao Subscrito ou Subscriber previamente inscrito no tópico. Da mesma
  forma, quando um cliente quer se tornar um Subscrito em um
  determinado tópico, ele encaminha uma mensagem de solicitação ao
  Broker, que fará essa interligação entre cliente e tópico.

  **Podemos simplificar em:**

  **Publicador/ Publisher:**  Quem envia dados para um tópico, emissor.

  **Subscrito/ Subscriber:**  Pessoa que está inscrita no tópico e recebe
  os dados, receptor.

  **Broker:** Intermédio de comunicação entre
  Publicador e Subscrito, responsável por receber, enfileirar e enviar
  as mensagens.

  **Payload:** Conteúdo da mensagem enviada. Cliente/Client:
  Elemento capaz de interagir com o Broker, seja para enviar, receber
  ou os dois.

  **Mensagem:** Pacote de dados trocados entre Clientes e
  Broker.

  **Tópico:** Endereço para o qual os dados serão encaminhados.

  **Unsubscribe:** Deixar de assinar um tópico.

  **Vale mencionar que um Cliente pode agir tanto como Publicador quanto Subscrito.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você tem três perguntas, então eu tenho três pontos:

- MQTT é um protocolo usado em IoT para enviar mensagens com três tipos de características: 1) As mensagens são assíncronas 2) as mensagens são enviadas como "Publicador e Subscritor" 3) as mensagens são pequenas.
- MQTT envia suas mensagens pelo protocolo TCP / IP.
- HTTP funciona também sobre TCP / IP, mas as diferenças estão entre as características: HTTP 1) é o protocolo síncrono 2) envia mensagens uma para uma 3) é um protocolo maior em parte dos títulos e seu próprio protocolo.

MQTT é otimizado para transferência de dados quando um número limitado de recursos está disponível, tanto na transferência de dados quanto na capacidade do dispositivo. O método de transmissão de dados que usa também não limita o número de remetentes ou destinatários.

Mais Informações:

[1] https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT

[2] https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/messaging/articles/iot-mqtt-why-good-for-iot/ (em inglês)

Answer (score -1):

1. MQTT é um protocolo de mensagens leve para sensores e pequenos
   dispositivos móveis otimizado para redes.
2. Ele utiliza TCP/IP
3. A maior diferença entre eles é o tamanho do payload. No HTTP o payload é maior, o que inviabiliza o uso em conexões de baixa qualidade. Além disso o MQTT possui maior segurança, apresenta mais níveis de serviço, é menos complexo e permite uma comunicação de 1 para N se comparado ao HTTP que também é um protocolo utilizado no universo de Internet das Coisas.